# Execute curl from R programming language?

Tags: r, curl

Is there a way to execute (various commands in) cURL from R programming language? 
Thank you.

Comment: The [`curl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html) or [`RCurl`](http://www.omegahat.net/RCurl/) packages?

Answer (score 1):

Use `system` command.

```
system("curl.exe param1 param2")
```

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html